# В чем может быть ошибка в discord.py selectmenu?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я использую discord.py и пытаюсь сделать SelectMenu, но выдает ошибку при запуске бота, в чем проблема? Строку с ошибкой указал ниже (только строка а не весь код):

```
    @bot.tree.command(name="join") 
    async def join(ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction):
```

Comment: А ошибку-то можно?

Comment: Может быть, то что у вас название функции совпадает с названием команды

Answer (score 0):

Уберите просто `ctx`:

```
    @bot.tree.command(name="join") 
    async def join(interaction: discord.Interaction):
```